# What does "Dominus providebit" mean?

Tags: meaning, latin-to-english-translation, grammar-identification

Does "Dominus providebit" mean "The Lord will provide" or "The Lord provides"?

I once had a bit of an argument with a guy who studied Latin over that. It's an inscription that appears on the rim of some old Swiss coins that I have.

Answer (score 6):

There might be more nuance to the matter, but from a purely grammatical point of view it is clear:
the form *providebit* is a future form, not present tense.
The corresponding present form would be *providet*.
Therefore "The Lord will provide" is a better translation.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a reference to Gen 22:8 and the sacrifice of Isaac.

Comment: I agree with Joonas, as providebit is the third-person singular future active indicative of prōvideō

Answer (score 3):

The "b" in *providebit* indicates future tense, while the "i" which follows the "b" is a connecting vowel having no significance other than ease of pronunciation.  So the word *providebit* literally means "He will provide", being the third person singular form of the verb. It is understood to be masculine, following the masculine form of the word *Dominus*, which is understood to be in the nominative case indicating that it is the subject of the sentence. The meaning is therefore understood as "The Lord will provide".

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate. The vowel isn't purely a connector, but there is some sort of schwa. Imperfect verbs also have a -b-, but the fuller form is -ba-.